# How to aduser with admin access while creating ad account facebook marketing api

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to create ad account in Facebook business manager via Facebook marketing and graph API using following code.

```
$attachment =  array('access_token'      => $this->accessToken,
                        'name'           => $associative_arr['name'],
                        'currency'       => $associative_arr['currency'],
                        'timezone_id'    => $associative_arr['timezone_id'],
                        'end_advertiser' => $this->mybusinessId,
                        'media_agency'   => 'NONE',
                        'partner'        => 'NONE',
                        'access_type'    => 'OWNER',
                        'permitted_roles' => 'ADMIN'
                        //'user_role'        => '1001'
                        );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$this->apiVersion.'/'.$this->mybusinessId.'/adaccount');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$dcde = json_decode($result);
curl_close ($ch);
```

It successfully creates ad account but does not add me as a user in people with administrative access.

Can anyone give me suggestion what can be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the ad account is created, you'll need to make another call which will add the user with the required permissions.

```
$attachment =  array(
    'access_token' => $this->accessToken,
    'business' => '<business_id>',
    'user' => '<user_id>',
    'role' => 'ADMIN'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$this->apiVersion.'/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/userpermissions');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$dcde = json_decode($result);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was searching on this from number of days.. Thanks

Comment: @Jass glad to help :)

Comment: @Jass, instead of writing curl calls manually its better to use the [Facebook Marketing Apis Sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/sdks)

Comment: @Haridarshan that is the right answer, that is the way I'm using it, and it works.