# Application does not have permission error when trying to add user to facebook ad account

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I have facebook business account. I am seeing following error.

```
(#10) Application does not have permission for this action
```

When trying to add user to ad account using following code.

```
$attachment = array('access_token' => $accessToken,
'uid' => $fb_user_id,
'role' => '1001');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_'.$ad_account_id.'/users');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I have already Ads Management Basic Access, Ads Management API Standard Access and business_management access level.

I am doing RND on this from last few days but not getting any hint what can be the problem so can anyone give me suggestions what can be the exact problem?

Comment: Check whether the **access_token** you're using is having extended permission or not. You can debug **access_token** using this url [Debug Facebook  Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/)

Comment: I was able to solve this by your suggestion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40128230/how-to-aduser-with-admin-access-while-creating-ad-account-facebook-marketing-api/40365998#40365998