# Graph returned an error requires extended permission business_management

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

My app has ads_management, business_management and standard level permissions so When I try to login in from my Facebook account then it retrieves information successfully. But when my customer login with fb then it shows error

```
Graph returned an error: (#200) Requires extended permission: business_management
```

I am making following API call v2.8

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
 'app_id'                 => $appId,
 'app_secret'         => $appSecret,
 'default_graph_version' => $graph_api_version,
]);

$response = $fb->get('/me/businesses', $accessToken);
```

[image]

[image]

What can be the reasons and possible solutions?

Comment: Is your facebook App reviewed by **Facebook Developer Team**. If not you will need to first submit it for **App Review** after that only you're customers can use that.

Comment: I guess, Yes because only after fb team review, we get permission of ads_management, business_management and standard level. Am I right or are you something else ?

Comment: Did you submitted the app for **App Review**. If you're listed as **developer/tester** in the **Roles** then without submitting for App Review  the **extended permissions** will work. For **App Review** you need to screencast the entire flow of the required extended permissions and submit it.

Comment: In FB > APP> APP review > I have business_management, email, public_profile, user_friends, Ads Management API Standard Access and Ads Management Basic Access

Comment: All these permissions are **green**??

Comment: If they are green than when you're creating  the facebook login url check whether the permissions are added or not.

Comment: Yes I submitted screen cast when I was taking approval of business_management and In roles I am acting as a administrator. Yes all permissions are green Let me attach 2 screen shots that will give more clarity to you

Comment: I have edited my post and added screen shots. Please check

Comment: _Approved_ by Facebook does not mean _granted_ by the user. You still need to _ask_ the user for the permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
 'app_id'                 => $appId,
 'app_secret'         => $appSecret,
 'default_graph_version' => $graph_api_version,
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = [
    'email', 
    'user_friends', 
    'manage_pages', 
    'business_management',
    'ads_management'
];


$fb_url = $helper->getLoginUrl(
    <callbackUrl>, 
    $permissions
);
```

Redirect use to this url. Facebook will redirect the user again back to the callback url after taking permissions from the user.
Once customer comes back to portal via this url, you will get the access token having permissions of the extended permission which you exchange for long-lived access token by short-lived access token and query the requried graph-api

**Callback Script**

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'                 => $appId,
    'app_secret'         => $appSecret,
    'default_graph_version' => $graph_api_version,
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Exchange short-lived access token with long-lived access token
if (!$accessToken->isLongLived()) {
    // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
    try {
        $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Store access token and redirect user where you query this

```
$response = $fb->get('/me/businesses', $accessToken);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. It worked. I have accepted your answer

Comment: Do you have any idea about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40128230/how-to-aduser-with-admin-access-while-creating-ad-account-facebook-marketing-api or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148315/application-does-not-have-permission-error-when-trying-to-add-user-to-facebook-a

Actually this is same question but asked in two ways